# What resistor is needed to regulate the current through 2 3V LEDs in series with a 9V battery?

Tags: voltage, led, resistors, dc

So I'm trying to power 2 of these [LED lights](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07P8PMCCS) together in series. I know that I have to add the voltage of the two lights together and get a resistor that restricts the power to that level. I have a 9V battery and the lights are 3V each. I brand new to all of this, and understand almost nothing, so any help would be appreciated. Can someone help me choose the correct resistor (And how to identify that resistor with the color branding thing) so two of those lights listed above can be wired in series?
Thanks!

Comment: You may want to check this:http://lednique.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Amazon page, the LEDs operate at 15mA, and their max current is 20mA. It is a bit confusing, but it looks like they drop 3V. Two of them would drop 6V. If you have a 9V battery, that is 3V that must be dropped across your resistor. (Of course the 9V battery will vary in voltage, but we will ignore that for now.)

To find the resistor divide the 3V by 15mA to get 200\$\Omega\$.

The color code for resistors can be found using [this chart](https://neurophysics.ucsd.edu/courses/physics_120/resistorcharts.pdf).

If you want to be a nerd, you can memorize the mnemonic Better Be Right Or Your Great Big Venture Goes West. (Black Brown Red Orange Yellow Green Blue Violet Gray White) for (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9). For resistors with 3 bands followed by a space and then a single band, the first two bands represent the first two significant digits. The third band represents an exponent of 10 to multiply by, and the lone band is the tolerance.

Comment: When someone asks, "What resistor is needed to power 2 3V LEDs in series ...," the first thing that pops to mind is a nice \$-4.7\:\Omega\$ resistor. Those babies will definitely help power the LEDs, just fine.

Comment: @jonk. Is that with or without a flux capacitor?

Comment: I like mine ala carte. :)

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but wouldn't I want to divide from 6V or 9V since 3V is only one light? Awesome explanation by the way.   “ To find the resistor divide the 3V by 15mA to get 200Ω.”

Comment: @Greenreader9 that particular 3V comes from subtracting 6V (two LEDs) from 9V (the supply). It is the voltage across the resistor.

Answer (score 1):

Consider each white LED as a 3V Zener with a 15 mA nominal rating and 20mA max.

Thus with 9V- (2x3V) = 3V. ... / 15mA = ? ohms